# Rspec Outside-In testing a .run method

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

I'm having issues modeling my tests to drive from the `.run` method down to the inner workings of the app.

The `.run` method is the sole point of entry for the application which has yet to be written. What you see below it just a quick mockup of how it *could* work.

`.run` is basically a factory which creates and instance of `Car`, adds some  Wheels & Doors and finally returns a string representation of the car.

Because of this, I'm not sure how to write my first tests to get started.

```
class Car
  attr_accessor :wheels, :doors

  def initialize
    @wheels = []
    @doors = []
  end

  def self.run(wheels, doors)
    car = Car.new
    car.wheels = Car::Wheel.load_json(wheels)
    car.doors = Car::Door.load_json(doors)
    car.build.to_s
  end
end

Car.run(wheels_json, doors_json)
```

Some thoughts I had:

- I could write an integration test but that won't really drive the development since an integration test would simply check that calling `.run` with two variables (wheels and doors) with json content in them will spit out a string representation of a car. I'll have to write a hell of a lot of code to make that test to pass.
- If `.run` was returning an instance of `Car` I could test by grabbing the returned instance but I can't do that since the method returns a string.

To be clear, the question is: Given the above code, how would you start testing to help you drive down and build the rest of the application.

Answer (score 0):

The basic principle of unit testing is that each unit (`Car::Wheel`, `Car::Door`) should be tested separately. When you compose two classes you can be sure, that the underlying elements are properly implemented.

Instead of having `run` method you should have methods with single responsibility (just build and not build & serialize):

```
  def self.build(wheels, doors)
    car = Car.new
    car.wheels = Car::Wheel.load_json(wheels)
    car.doors = Car::Door.load_json(doors)
    car
  end

  def self.run(wheels, doors)
    self.build.to_s
  end
```

This way you can easily test output of `build` method as it return an object.